# Return all matched and unmatched values in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table, something like this (simplified):

1. products with column id and title
2. outlet data with column id,
       product id, and shelf share percentage

I have some data of products in outlet data. I want all the products that are in outlet data with the shelf share percentage and I also want the product that aren't in outlet data. I have implement left outer join but it only returns products that are in outlet data. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT a.title, b.shelf_share_percentage
                    FROM cp_product a
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN cp_outlet_data b
                    ON a.id = b.product_id 
                    WHERE b.plan_id='9d9184ff-b848-4515-97a2-cea63caddd67'
                    AND b.visit_id='1586bfd3-8a1b-4f3a-bbc7-eaf61774bb50'    
                    AND b.town_id='414'
                    AND b.category_id='6'
                    AND b.shelf_share_id='3'
                    AND b.outlet_id='0331d624-6fcf-4ac9-8a73-3b60882c5136'
```

How can I get all the matched and unmatched products?

Comment: Would it really hurt to have two simpler, easier  to maintain, queries?

Comment: I wish it would've been like that but the scenario that I'm working on requires me to have a join of both the table. @Mawg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move all the conditions on the `cp_outlet_data` from the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    a.title,
    b.shelf_share_percentage
FROM cp_product a
LEFT JOIN cp_outlet_data b
    ON a.id = b.product_id AND
       b.plan_id = '9d9184ff-b848-4515-97a2-cea63caddd67'  AND
       b.visit_id = '1586bfd3-8a1b-4f3a-bbc7-eaf61774bb50' AND
       b.town_id = 414                                     AND
       b.shelf_share_id = 3                                AND
       b.outlet_id = '0331d624-6fcf-4ac9-8a73-3b60882c5136'
WHERE
    b.category_id = 6;
```

What is happening in your current query is that, while a left join is initially including all the records from `cp_product`, even if they do not match, the subsequent `WHERE` clause is removing certain records.  By adding the `WHERE` logic to the `ON` clause, all the records will still be retained.

Comment: Your query works fine but it returns all the products. Is there a way where it can only return the products with category_id = '6'?

Comment: @3iL In this case, move the check on `category_id` back to the `WHERE` clause, q.v. my updated answer.